# User logs in without asking for password , and can't log out of user and also can't lock screen?

Tags: login, password

I have just installed Ubuntu, and set a password while installing which it was `1234` , and then after I was done installing I wanted to change it, but when I went to the user account and unlocked it, and then typed the current password and new password, I wasn't able to click on the change button.

I tried the command `passwd {user}` and it worked, now when I try to use `sudo` command or install any software, I use the new password, but the problem is that I can't log out of the account or lock the screen any more. Also when I boot my device and try to access my user, the computer doesn't ask for a password, I just see a button that says *login* without asking for any password.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to user accounts

Then select your user and double click.

click Unlock in the upper right hand corner. (should work now that you set password from terminal) enter new password.

On same screen make sure  "Automatic Login" is turned off for your account.

Comment: Thank you for helping , but no it didn't work and yeah i made sure "Automatic login" is turned off my account.
The {change} button can't be clicked on.

Comment: Do you recommend reinstalling ubuntu , and this might be just an error , or there must be a way to troubleshoot it?

Comment: Must be a way to troubleshoot. Will look into as can, or maybe someone else can chime in. Rather that a complete reinstall (as a last resort) you might be better  off creating a new user with sudo access. Delete old user, and then create old user again. Not really a fix, but more of a work around.

Comment: I thought about it , however I tried to creat a new account by using "user accounts" and also couldn't set a password for it , and no i didn't try using terminal for creating one ,(don't know how) . but i might give it a shot . help me please...

Comment: From terminal `sudo adduser username` will create user and then `sudo adduser username sudo` will add user to sudoers. But if your having trouble creating account, this may not do anything to help

Comment: This might work , but i just need to know if the apps are installed on the new user as well, or not?

Comment: Anything you installed with apt-get would be there. Not sure about other things. But the fact that you can't even create account from user account section makes me think your still going to have issues. You may be able to log in with password as desired, but something still up with user accounts program. Not sure if that can be purged and reinstalled.

Comment: What about transferring date?....can it be done without using hdd or something?
so you think that there is something wrong with the os not the user itself?

Comment: You can make a backup folder in home directory of new user and move things there. Or you can get cloud storage from box.com and mount the drive in Ubuntu and move things there.  See my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/578616/davfs-user-group-for-remote-directory-mount/578633#578633)

Comment: Thank you , i will try it now and let you know what happens.

Comment: I might go the box route as that will give you 10gig of storage. Then if you need to reinstall, you know all your data is in the cloud on box